# Display Year and Month from custom field + Age Calculator

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, date, date-time

I have a custom field "DOB" on my custom post type which is in [Ymd] format. I want to compare that date of birth to current time and want to show "You are # years # months."

I am able to calculate Years only but it is not accurate. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You create two date objects and compare with the `diff()` methode.

```
$from = new DateTime( '1970-01-01' );
$to = new DateTime('today');
$years = $from->diff($to)->y;
$months =  $from->diff($to)->m;

echo $years . ' years and ' . $months . ' months.';
```

=> 46 years and 1 months.

Comment: Thanks Soren but What if we want to display 46 years and 213 days ? in that format ?